# Move each filename into filename subfolders

Tags: files, scripts

I have a directory structure like this

```
file 1.ext1
file 1.ext2
file 1.ext3
file 2.temp.ext1
file 2.ext2
file 3.ext1
```

I want to create each subfolder and move each file name no matter what extension there

```
file 1\file 1.ext1
file 1\file 1.ext2
file 1\file 1.ext3
file 2\file 2.temp.ext1
file 2\file 2.ext2
file 3\file 3.ext1
```

any easy way to do it? thanks

Comment: @muru That's the other way round, right? Grouping by extension?

Comment: @Sparhawk I see it as a simple extension of that answer. (Instead of using B in `A.B`, use `A`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'base=$(echo $1 | grep -oP "(?<=\./).*(?=\.[^\.]*$)"); mkdir -p "${base}"; mv "$1" "$base"' . {} \;
```

#### Explanation

- `find . -type f` This script will operate on all "regular" files (i.e. will not work on the current directory `.`).
- `-exec sh -c '...' . {} \;` execute the `'...`' part, with the filename fed to the script as an argument (and accessed by `$1`).
- `base=$(echo $1 | grep -oP "(?<=\./).*(?=\.[^\.]*$)");` derive the base part of the filename. i.e. `grep` out the part after `./` and before the final `.`.
- `mkdir -p "${base}";` Create the directory (e.g. `file1`).
- `mv "$1" "$base"` Move the file into the newly created directory.

---

If you prefer files such as `file1.temp.ext1` to move to the directory `file1`, instead of `file1.temp`, then you can use the following instead.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'base=$(echo $1 | grep -oP "(?<=\./)[^\.]*(?=\..*$)"); mkdir -p "${base}"; mv "$1" "$base"' . {} \;
```

#### Explanation

- `(?<=\./)[^\.]*(?=\..*$)` The only part that differs is the regular expression to capture the "base" part of the filename, where the new directory will be created. This now captures up to the first `.`, instead of the last `.`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @muru, I didn't know the `-p` flag suppressed warnings.

Comment: Only if the directory already exists. :)

Comment: @muru Ah yes, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: quick question, how to avoid if a file name is "file1.temp.ext1" so it does not move to directory "file1.temp" but to directory: "file1"

Comment: @TheOski I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this will suffice:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#this script sorts files according to their extensions
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
(find . -type f) > /tmp/temp
for var in `cat /tmp/temp`
do
    name=`basename "$var"`
    name=`echo $name | cut -d'.' -f1`
    mkdir -p $name
    mv "$var" $name/ 2> /dev/null
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Comment: It's bad practice to reproduce one of your old answers pretty much as-is as a new answer. You should flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @muru i thought the question is lil different because it says not to move in a folder named by extension but by name of the file